# How to rotate text in table cells?

Tags: python-docx

I'm trying to make table like this:

[image: Table with vertical header cells]

As you can see, the header is vertically orientated.
How can I achieve this using python-docx?

P.S. Sorry for non-translated table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snippet for those who are too tired to seek:

```
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.table import _Cell


def set_vertical_cell_direction(cell: _Cell, direction: str):
    # direction: tbRl -- top to bottom, btLr -- bottom to top
    assert direction in ("tbRl", "btLr")
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
    textDirection = OxmlElement('w:textDirection')
    textDirection.set(qn('w:val'), direction)  # btLr tbRl
    tcPr.append(textDirection)
```