# how to rotate text in the table cell

Tags: python, python-pptx

Do you know how to rotate text in the table cell?
This is code sample:

```
shp = slide.shapes.add_table(rows+dop_rows, cols+dop_cols, left, top, width, height)
table = shp.table
table.cell(i,j).text ='something text'
```

But I didn't find anything about text rotation or text direction in the text frame objects.

I use python pptx release with last version 0.6.17

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738013/how-to-rotate-text-in-table-cells/50128963  looks similar

Comment: that is different, because I use python-pptx. In quoted question author used python-docx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked a bit with the workaround functions and got the result.
To rotate text in the table cell we have to do folowing:

```
the_cell = temp_table.cell(i,j)# get the cell instance object
tcpr = the_cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
tcpr.set('vert','vert270')# setting 'vert' parameter to 'vert270'
prs.save('test.pptx')
```