# How to get cell text rotation in docx with python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I'm writing Python script to get data from MS Word table and to draw such table another application. So I can't solve the issue how to get info on cell text rotation in existing Word document.

I used the [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738013/how-to-rotate-text-in-table-cells/50128963#50128963) on setting cell text rotation.

```py
def get_vertical_cell_direction(cell: _Cell):       
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()    
    return tcPr
```

This code returns this: "CT_TcPr  at 0x2e102875958>"
Reading docx documentation I'm pretty confused what to do next to get textDirection property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324814/how-to-get-cell-background-color-in-python-docx/58365527#58365527) I asked, it needed to check xml code of a cell:

```
def get_text_direction(cell):    
    # direction: tbRl -- top to bottom, btLr -- bottom to top
    pattern = re.compile('w:textDirection w:val=\"(\S*)\"')
    match = pattern.search(cell._tc.xml)
    if match:
        txt = match.group(1)
        if txt == 'btLr':
            return 90
        elif  txt == 'tbRl':
            return -90
    return 0
```