# How to get cell background color in python-docx?

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, python-docx

I'm trying to read data from MS Word table using python-docx.
There is a way to set background color of a table cell:

```
tcPr = cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
shd = OxmlElement("w:shd")
shd.set(qn("w:fill"), rgb2hex(*color))
tcPr.append(shd)
```

My task is contrary, I need to get the existing color. I'm not skilled in xml and I tried this:

```
cell = table.cell(row, col)
tcPr = cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().get(qn('w:shd'))
```

How ever it returns me *None* for each read cell regardless of its color.

Comment: I think you'll find there's more than one way in the XML to shade the background of a cell. Best bet is to call `print(cell._tc.xml)` for a cell you know has shading so you can see what you're looking for exactly.

Comment: Thanks! After your hint I solved my question.

Comment: I just added and answer to clarify the right method to use when looking for a tcPr child node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [scanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902513/scanny) proposed, I used parsing cell._tc.xml:

```
pattern = re.compile('w:fill=\"(\S*)\"')
match = pattern.search(cell._tc.xml)
result = match.group(1)
```

If there is data on color it returns either "auto" or hex code of background color which can be converted to RGB.

Comment: Yessssssssssssss

Answer (score 2):

As [scanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902513/scanny) said, you should first be sure of the element/property you are looking for.

But to read the value of this element you should rather use the find method.

Ex:

```
cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().get(qn('w:shd')) #Returns None
cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().find(qn('w:shd')) #Returns <Element {http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}shd at ...>
```