# Having issue with text direction, in table cell - python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I am currently facing a problem with text direction of a text in table cell. I wanted to change my texts direction in cells of the first row of a table, to be from bottom to top. So, I search the internet and I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738013/how-to-rotate-text-in-table-cells). It did work especially in wordpad. However, I found out that in libre office and Wicrosoft Word 2016 the table cell height remain fixed - the cell height did not expand to accommodate the text.
Is this an issue with python-docx or is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the only problem that the cell didn't adjust height? Did the text actually rotate to display sideways?

Comment: Yes. The only problem is that the height did not adjust.. The text is rotating.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see the word, SIDEWAYS, in your comment. What do you actually mean? Did you mean from left to right? If that is what you meant, I think that is the default direction of text in word document. What I really want is for the text to rotate from bottom to top and at the same time the height of the cell to adjust to fit the text. It did rotate as I want but, the problem is the cell height is not adjusting.